# Making sure that every group in pandas has the same products

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

| date | company_id | product_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-30 | 001 | 1 | 200 |
| 2020-11-30 | 002 | 2 | 150 |
| 2020-12-30 | 001 | 1 | 50 |
| 2020-12-30 | 001 | 2 | 400 |
| 2020-12-30 | 002 | 3 | 300 |
| 2020-12-30 | 001 | 4 | 350 |
| 2021-01-30 | 002 | 1 | 600 |
| 2021-01-30 | 001 | 2 | 400 |
| 2021-01-30 | 002 | 4 | 100 |
| 2021-01-30 | 001 | 5 | 50 |
| 2021-01-30 | 002 | 6 | 35 |
| 2021-01-30 | 001 | 7 | 400 |

I need to work out what the difference between sales today and the previous day by company_id, this is easily solved by converting this to pandas dataframe, grouping by company_id and doing a shift. However, if the sales are 0 the product is not reported, this means when I do shift I get 0 for the change rather than an increase / decrease.

I tried the below, which is basically getting the list of all products by company_id and if they are not reported adding them with a 0, but this doesn't seem to work properly and also takes forever to run.

```
company_ids= set(df['company_id'].tolist())
for company_id company_ids:
    full_prod_list= set(df[df['company_id'] == company_id]['product_id'].tolist())
    for date in set(df[df['company_id'] == company_id]['date'].tolist()):
        date_prod_list =  set(df[(df['product_id'] == product_id) & (df['date'] == date)]['product_id'].tolist())
        diff = [x for x in full_prod_list if x not in date_prod_list]
        for i in diff:
            df.loc[len(df)]=[date, company_id, i, 0]
```

For example November should look like this:

| date | company_id | product_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-30 | 001 | 1 | 200 |
| **2020-11-30** | **001** | **2** | **0** |
| **2020-11-30** | **001** | **4** | **0** |
| **2020-11-30** | **001** | **5** | **0** |
| **2020-11-30** | **001** | **7** | **0** |
| **2020-11-30** | **002** | **1** | **0** |
| 2020-11-30 | 002 | 2 | 150 |
| **2020-11-30** | **002** | **3** | **0** |
| **2020-11-30** | **002** | **4** | **0** |
| **2020-11-30** | **002** | **6** | **0** |

Thanks

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal, at the bottom, the formatting is bit messed up, but should be readbale

Comment: Are you saying that you want to transform the original df so that it contains for each date a unique row for each company and product and sales entry, then using the transformed df, group by day and determine the sales diff from the previous day?

Answer (score 0):

The code that I provided works, however it takes a very long time to run (over 30m for a dataset of 69k rows)

Converting the last for loop into append with a new data frame cuts this time down to 30sec.

```
company_ids= set(df['company_id'].tolist())
for company_id company_ids:
    full_prod_list= set(df[df['company_id'] == company_id]['product_id'].tolist())
    for date in set(df[df['company_id'] == company_id]['date'].tolist()):
        date_prod_list =  set(df[(df['product_id'] == product_id) & (df['date'] == date)]['product_id'].tolist())
        diff = [x for x in full_prod_list if x not in date_prod_list]
        insert = [[date] * len(diff), [company_id] * len(diff), diff, [0] * len(diff)]
        append_df = pd.DataFrame (insert).transpose()
        append_df.columns = df.columns
        df = df.append(append_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach:

```
pd_catType = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=list(set(df['product_id'])), ordered=True)
ci_catType = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=list(set(df['company_id'])), ordered=True)
df['product_id'] = df['product_id'].astype(pd_catType)
df['company_id'] = df['company_id'].astype(ci_catType)
df.set_index(['date','company_id', 'product_id'], inplace= True)
cats = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(cats).reset_index()
df['sales'] = df['sales'].fillna(0)
```

For the example you provided this yields:

```
date    company_id  product_id  sales
0   2020-11-30  002 1   0.0
1   2020-11-30  002 2   150.0
2   2020-11-30  002 3   0.0
3   2020-11-30  002 4   0.0
4   2020-11-30  002 5   0.0
5   2020-11-30  002 6   0.0
6   2020-11-30  002 7   0.0
7   2020-11-30  001 1   200.0
8   2020-11-30  001 2   0.0
9   2020-11-30  001 3   0.0
10  2020-11-30  001 4   0.0
11  2020-11-30  001 5   0.0
12  2020-11-30  001 6   0.0
13  2020-11-30  001 7   0.0
14  2020-12-30  002 1   0.0
15  2020-12-30  002 2   0.0
16  2020-12-30  002 3   300.0
17  2020-12-30  002 4   0.0
18  2020-12-30  002 5   0.0
19  2020-12-30  002 6   0.0
20  2020-12-30  002 7   0.0
21  2020-12-30  001 1   50.0
22  2020-12-30  001 2   400.0
23  2020-12-30  001 3   0.0
24  2020-12-30  001 4   350.0
25  2020-12-30  001 5   0.0
26  2020-12-30  001 6   0.0
27  2020-12-30  001 7   0.0
28  2021-01-30  002 1   600.0
29  2021-01-30  002 2   0.0
30  2021-01-30  002 3   0.0
31  2021-01-30  002 4   100.0
32  2021-01-30  002 5   0.0
33  2021-01-30  002 6   35.0
34  2021-01-30  002 7   0.0
35  2021-01-30  001 1   0.0
36  2021-01-30  001 2   400.0
37  2021-01-30  001 3   0.0
38  2021-01-30  001 4   0.0
39  2021-01-30  001 5   50.0
40  2021-01-30  001 6   0.0
41  2021-01-30  001 7   400.0
```

Comment: thank you @itprorh66, but does this code assume that every company reports on the same days? I get an error ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! and by looking at the df before pd.MultiIndex I see some null values for dates.

Comment: As per my original comment, I thought that was what you wanted.  Are you saying you want to transform the original df so that you have a unique row for each product for each company that reports a transaction for a day?

Comment: Yes, but they don't report on the same days. So company 1 would report monthly, and company 2 would report daily.